# code invalid according to W3C - dont know how to solve these

Tags: html, css, w3c

I have a rather big website, but it has 31 errors.
I seriously dont know how to fix these.

any help on any error fix would be appreciated. Even some i dont know why it displays an error:

http://www.horecavacaturebank.nl

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.horecavacaturebank.nl%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You chose XHTML 1.0 Transitional as your doc type. Read [the XHTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) for debugging invalid code. If you're writing in XHTML, all tags need to be closed, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my experience abt w3c validation, just read carefully and is tells itself what is problem, here in you page attributes used like rel are not what can say w3c not defined or permitted yet, one more simple error there used li tag but parent tag should be there either ul or ol.
More to say is we have to validate when our design part completes, after code integration  or session starts it doesn't works.